# import styled This expression is not callable. ts(2349)

Tags: typescript, gatsby, styled-components, tsconfig, .d.ts

I couldn't find any solution for this thing on the web. Before I added `gatsby-plugin-resolve-src` to my gatsby project, everything was working as expected.

To add `gatsby-plugin-resolve-src` to the project, the docs say that the following should be added to ***tsconfig.json***

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "types/*",
        "*"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

And it does work, but `styled-components` is not recognized any more.

`import styled, {css} from 'styled-components'` throws this-

> import styled
> This expression is not callable. ts(2349)

> Module '"styled-components"' has no exported member 'css'. ts(2305)

So if I comment out the added props in ***tsconfig.json***, everything reverts back to the working state but the plugin doesn't work.

I think the reason why this is the case with `styled-components` only, is because I have a custom definition file for it.

**src/types/styled-components.d.ts**

```
import 'styled-components';

declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    primary: string;
    secondary: string;
    .....
  }
}
```

This is my complete tsconfig-

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2017"],
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*", "*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["/node_modules/"]
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the `styled-components` type definitions?

```
npm i styled-components
npm i @types/styled-components --save-dev
```

Can you share a sample repo, in order to better see the required paths and dependencies?

Comment: I'm already using the @types. I'm sure that the issue lies in the way I'm using the declaration file. There are two things happening- 
1. If apply the tsconfig's two properties (in order to use the resolve plugin), the types for `styled-components`  don't work.
2. The default types do work if I delete `.d.ts` file.
So it's either the tsconfig properties or the d.ts file that needs to be fixed.